# Best way to simulate default value for TEXT column using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using a TEXT column in my MySQL database. As the documentation says, it is not possible to set a default value for these columns.

I'm currently using the following code to simulate this behavior:

```
class Data
  before_save lambda {text_column ||= ''}
end
```

Is there any better, more railis/active_record way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with a HTML5 solution, have you tried a :placeholder attribute on the :text_field?

Also do you really want to stuff a text_field (which captures a small amount of text) into a "text" type column? Did you mean text_area?

If you want the "default value" to actually be stored in the database if the user doesnt input anything then i suggest the following. It's the "Factory" pattern.

Instead of calling "new" on your ActiveRecord model class, you create a "setup" method in your model

```
def self.setup(params = {})
  new(params).tap do |v|
    v.text_column = "default value"
    # other defaultings
  end
end
```

In your controller instead of calling new on the class you call setup.

Comment: You seem do have taken the 'text_field' thing from an earlier answer:-)

I'm actually using a wysiwyg text editor to allow editing this field. And this text editor does actually set an empty string anyway.

Comment: But I'm doing things like imports with these objects where I'm not using a form/view.

Nice tips about :placeholder and the Factory pattern! They don't seem to be more Rails/ActiveRecord like than my single line hack, though. So I probably stay with it.

Comment: @Simon, Factory pattern is very highly recommended Rails best practice. Using the factory pattern is completely independent of the controller or view, in fact it is ideal for your import program to invoke the setup method on your model and expect default to get set. You could also consider implementing the after_initialize method in your model. This gets invoked after every new (but also after every find!!). There are active_record default related plugins too. http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_default_values.html

Comment: A small comment about the before_save lambda in your question. perhaps you wanted to have {self.text_column ||= "default value"}. And if you did, there would have been no way to nullify or empty the column if you so wished. So perhaps before_create might be something you wished to hook to. Yet another suggestion, is that you hook before/after callbacks to methods in your model which makes them more usable.

Comment: Well I'm actually want to set it to '' as the default value, and the reason is that I don't want to have 'two kinds of empty'. The reason is that I'm using the paper_trail gem to track changes and don't want users to be bothered about a field changing form 'empty' (nil/null) to 'empty' (empty string).

Answer (score -4):

Add this in your migration

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, :default => 'your text'
```

Working for me

Comment: He's got a text column not a string column!

Comment: It's the combination of MySQL and TEXT or BLOB column type that doesn't accept default values. This would be my preferred way in any other case.

Comment: its a text column

Answer (score -4):

If you have a text field in a form for new, use a default value of this text field:

```
#views/controller/new.html.erb
<%= f.text_field :column_name, :value => "default value" %>
```

It is a good usability choice, since user is aware of the default value of that column.

Don't use it in `edit.html.erb` though, since in this case this filed will still have the default value, regardless of its original value in database.

Comment: Wouldnt this always show the value of the text_field as "default value" even if i have "something else" in the database?

Comment: @Aditya Sanghi - Yes, you are right. This code should be used in a view for creating new new object. I'll put in explicitly in my answer.

Comment: You mean you havent dried up your form in a partial?? :)

Comment: As you see in my other comments, this is about the model, not about the view. (Thanx for trying to answer despite the vote-down:-)